# Look up parameters based on a numpy array of input values

Tags: python, beginner, numpy, lookup

**Aim:** Write a function that looks up empirical parameters `A`, `B` and `C` for a  solar radiation model. Each parameter has a value for a certain interval of time, represented as the day of the year. For now, I basically translate the four-column (`day_of_year`-interval, `A`, `B`, `C`) table that I have on paper into the following look up. The function works, but I have a feeling that this is not the most Pythonic way to do it.

**Current implementation:**

```
import numpy as np

def lookup_DNI_parameters(day_of_year):
    """Sets parameters A, B, and C for the calculation of direct normal irradiance
    based on day of year-intervals.

    A is in W/m^2
    B and C are dimensionless
    """
    A = np.empty_like(day_of_year)
    B = np.empty_like(day_of_year)
    C = np.empty_like(day_of_year)

    # generate boolean indices for each day_of_year-interval
    interval_1 = np.logical_and(day_of_year >=1, day_of_year < 32)
    interval_2 = np.logical_and(day_of_year >= 32, day_of_year < 60)
    interval_3 = np.logical_and(day_of_year >= 60, day_of_year < 91)
    interval_4 = np.logical_and(day_of_year >= 91, day_of_year < 121)
    interval_5 = np.logical_and(day_of_year >= 121, day_of_year < 152)
    interval_6 = np.logical_and(day_of_year >= 152, day_of_year < 182)
    interval_7 = np.logical_and(day_of_year >= 182, day_of_year < 213)
    interval_8 = np.logical_and(day_of_year >= 213, day_of_year < 244)
    interval_9 = np.logical_and(day_of_year >= 244, day_of_year < 274)
    interval_10 = np.logical_and(day_of_year >= 274, day_of_year < 305)
    interval_11 = np.logical_and(day_of_year >= 305, day_of_year < 335)
    interval_12 = day_of_year >= 335

    # set parameter values based on the interval
    A[interval_1] = 1230.0
    A[interval_2] = 1215.0
    A[interval_3] = 1186.0
    A[interval_4] = 1136.0
    A[interval_5] = 1104.0
    A[interval_6] = 1088.0
    A[interval_7] = 1085.0
    A[interval_8] = 1107.0
    A[interval_9] = 1152.0
    A[interval_10] = 1193.0
    A[interval_11] = 1221.0
    A[interval_12] = 1234.0

    B[interval_1] = 0.142
    B[interval_2] = 0.144
    B[interval_3] = 0.156
    B[interval_4] = 0.180
    B[interval_5] = 0.196
    B[interval_6] = 0.205
    B[interval_7] = 0.207
    B[interval_8] = 0.201
    B[interval_9] = 0.177
    B[interval_10] = 0.160
    B[interval_11] = 0.149
    B[interval_12] = 0.142

    C[interval_1] = 0.058
    C[interval_2] = 0.060
    C[interval_3] = 0.071
    C[interval_4] = 0.097
    C[interval_5] = 0.121
    C[interval_6] = 0.134
    C[interval_7] = 0.136
    C[interval_8] = 0.122
    C[interval_9] = 0.092
    C[interval_10] = 0.073
    C[interval_11] = 0.063
    C[interval_12] = 0.057

    return A, B, C

# test an array of a few sample days for correctness of results
days = np.array([21., 80., 141., 202., 264., 325.])
A, B, C = lookup_DNI_parameters(days)
print A # [1230, 1186, 1104, 1085, 1152, 1221]
print B # [0.142, 0.156, 0.196, 0.207, 0.177, 0.149]
print C # [0.058, 0.060, 0.071, 0.121, 0.136, 0.092, 0.063]
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Is this example code? It is always best to post your real working code to get the best out of a code review on this site. If this is example code, there is a chance your question could be closed as off-topic.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the welcome. I originally posted the question to stackoverflow and got asked to post it here because the code in principle works, so sorry if it is inapproriate here. It is kind of example / prototype code because I honestly gave up on the real code for now (i.e. it doesn't work at the moment) due to its messiness. The real code really doesn't do (/isn't supposed to do) anything else, apart from a few more parameters than `A` and `B` and similar `idx`s though.

Comment: I see. I'll leave it up for Python reviewers to decide whether this code is reviewable.

Comment: Please see [_Why is hypothetical example code off-topic for Code Review?_](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1709/9357). Generic identifiers like `A` and `idx_2` and magic numbers like `22` make it hard for us to figure out what you are really trying to accomplish. I think you'll get better reviews if you show us your real code, so I'll put this question on hold to give you a chance to alter it.

Comment: Actually, `A`, `B` and `C` are the actual parameter's names in the paper (not uncommon for empirical constants). I will follow the rules and add additional code and context, but I am convinced that the question and the code review will not benefit from any additional code. The task I want to accomplish is: Look up parameters based on the day of the year. There is nothing more to the real code, except a repetition of the same task for more `doy`-intervals. Again, just for clarification - I'll now re-write the rest of the code and provide context (can't copy my old code as I'm out of office now)

Comment: So where should a question like this be asked?  I've answered plenty like it on Stackoverflow.

Comment: I was actually sent here from Stackoverflow, the reason being that the code works, so I am equally confused. (n.b.: It actually doesn't work properly: The logical or should be an and. This was also in the real code, though. *cough*)

Comment: At this level of coding, `numpy` and `MATLAB` practices are similar.  There is a `numpy.where` function, but that is only for one conditional (and its complement).

Comment: Sounds like there are people on SO that don't have a clear idea of what is appropriate for CR.

Comment: I also felt like the question was suitable for SO, but I read somewhere that the difference between SO and CR is "why is my code broken" vs. "why is my code ugly", so I kinda see why one would send me here when my code works. Anyway, I have added / just re-written the rest of the code... as I said, I don't feel like it adds anything since I basically repeated the same task a few times and renamed a few variables, but well. I hope this is in accordance with the rules now. Thanks in advance for any helpful comments/answers!

Comment: Your expanded example does suggest some alternatives that weren't apparent with just 2 intervals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you are doing a lookup over many intervals.  A repeated pattern like that can be turned into a loop or vectorized

The repeated boilerplate suggests an iterative solution - looping over an array (or list) of dates and values.  It doesn't save on run time, and may, or may not, be more maintainable.

```
def lookup_DNI_parameters1(day_of_year):
    """solution based on iterating over ranges of dates
    """
    A = np.empty_like(day_of_year)
    dates = [1, 32, 60, 91, 121, 152, 182, 213, 244, 274, 305, 335, 366]
    Avalues = [1230.0, 1215.0, 1186.0, 1136.0, 1104.0, 1088.0, 1085.0, 1107.0, 1152.0, 1193.0, 1221.0, 1234.0]
    for i in range(len(dates)-1):
        interval = np.logical_and(day_of_year >= dates[i], day_of_year < dates[i+1])
        A[interval] = Avalues[i]
    # similarly for B and C
    return A
```

The operation can also be vectorized (in MATLAB as well as numpy), by constructing a matrix that compares the whole `day_of_year` array against the dates intervals array(s).  The `[:,None]` broadcasting may be novel to a `MATLAB` user.

```
def lookup_DNI_parameters2(day_of_year):
    """solution based on vectorized matching of days
    """
    dates = [1, 32, 60, 91, 121, 152, 182, 213, 244, 274, 305, 335, 366]
    dates1 = np.array(dates[:-1]) # interval start
    dates2 = np.array(dates[1:]) # interval stop
    Avalues = [1230.0, 1215.0, 1186.0, 1136.0, 1104.0, 1088.0, 1085.0, 1107.0, 1152.0, 1193.0, 1221.0, 1234.0]
    Avalues = np.array(Avalues)
    I = (dates1[:,None] <= day_of_year) & (day_of_year < dates2[:,None]) # boolean index array
    I = np.where(I)[0]  # convert to numeric index
    return Avalues[I]
```

Or this could be generalized to use a `dates` parameter, and a `values` array that has information for `A`, `B` and `C`:

```
def lookup_DNI_parameters3(day_of_year, dates, values):
    """solution based on vectorized matching of days
    """
    dates1 = np.array(dates[:-1]) # interval start
    dates2 = np.array(dates[1:]) # interval stop
    I = (dates1[:,None] <= day_of_year) & (day_of_year < dates2[:,None]) # boolean index array
    I = np.where(I)[0]  # convert to numeric index
    return values[...,I]

dates = [1, 32, 60, 91,...]
values = np.array([[1230.0, 1215.0,...], [142., 144., ...], [...]])
lookup_DNI_parameters3(day_of_years, dates, values)
```

Comment: This is great, thank you for taking the time. I also see now why what I considered to be unnecessary repetitive code may have helped you get a better idea of possible simplifications.